# how to prevent page going to home page on refreshing in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am using ajax in our web application and load form in a  tag after the response from the server using innerhtml()

but when i refresh the page using f5 then my application page goes to the first page of the application

How i can prevent this

Comment: You can use pjax https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: You need to change the location of the `window` to change the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, using cookies (I wouldn't recommend), using the url hash tag/anchor tag and parsing the data after the # with javascript, or use the [history API](http://html5demos.com/history)

Don't use jQuery, unless you are lazy.

Comment: i don't know how to use url hash tag

Comment: You can use document.location.hash to get all text after the # and including the #, so you would want to do a substr from the begging to get rid of it.

Comment: See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at jQuery BBQ which allows you to save the ajax state.
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

example (warning don't go there if you're hungry):
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/#kebabs.html

Comment: i try this example with "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" but its not working  do i need to add another file for this

Comment: Yes the BBQ files obviously: Download [Source](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/v1.2.1/jquery.ba-bbq.js), [Minified](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/v1.2.1/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js) (4.0kb)

Comment: thanks for your instant reply. I am trying this but its not working for me. My problem is that on click of button of form1, i setting the html of form2 in form1 and refreshing the page but it show me the previous html of form1 but i want to show the html of form2 on refreshing